# C# Can't drag my button with mouse

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-express

So i searched a little around on google to find some code to drag buttons with the mouse. I found a lot, even though none of these actually worked for me.

So i'm asking you! :-)

The code i'm trying to get working in my form:

```
bool isDragged = false;
  Point ptOffset;
  private void button1_MouseDown( object sender, MouseEventArgs e )
  {
     if ( e.Button == MouseButtons.Left )
     {
        isDragged = true;
        Point ptStartPosition = button1.PointToScreen(new Point(e.X, e.Y));

        ptOffset = new Point();
        ptOffset.X = button1.Location.X - ptStartPosition.X;
        ptOffset.Y = button1.Location.Y - ptStartPosition.Y;
     }
     else
     {
        isDragged = false;
     }
  }

  private void button1_MouseMove( object sender, MouseEventArgs e )
  {
     if ( isDragged )
     {
        Point newPoint = button1.PointToScreen(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        newPoint.Offset(ptOffset);
        button1.Location = newPoint;
     }
  }

  private void button1_MouseUp( object sender, MouseEventArgs e )
  {
     isDragged = false;
  }
```

I of course changed the pictureBox1 to button1.

But i just can't get this to work.

Anyone who might know why?

Oh, and i want to use this at all my buttons, so what should i replace button1 with to make it work at all of the buttons?

-Btw, i use Visual studio Express.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you're trying to move the buttons on your application when you click on them? wouldn't that negate the point of having buttons, since they'll just move around ...?

Comment: Oh.. You know for example iphone, where the apps can be clicked on as buttons, but if you hold the screen you can edit where you want the apps to be. I'm kinda creating something where you can move the content around. :)

Comment: you targeting phone? windows? winforms? wpf?

Comment: Windows :) I want to create like a second desktop when studying, so i can be more focused on the studying, instead of all my icons on the desktop and stuff.

Comment: Have you considered [Fences](http://www.guidingtech.com/5416/quickly-hide-desktop-icons-windows/) or something like [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/create-a-shortcut-or-hotkey-to-turn-the-desktop-icons-on-or-off/) ? It will save you the time coding it yourself, and you can focus on your studies :)

Comment: Well, i know how to hide my desktop icons. :) (I'm on an IT school, so i have to learn programming.) I'm mostly doing this too because i would like to become an experienced programmer, even though i'm really just copy pasting when it comes to windows forms. I also would like to create this to try making a smooth desktop layout like you see in CSI or any other crime TV show. You know, where you can just drag an image in, and close it by voice control (I've done something like that with my Kinect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> even though i'm really just copy pasting when it comes to windows
>   forms

The code you posted won't actually do anything by itself!

To work, the MouseDown() and MouseMove() events of the control have to be wired up to those methods:

1. Select the control on the form (pictureBox1).
2. In the Properties Pane (bottom right by default), click the
   "Lightning Bolt" icon to get a list of the events for that control.
3. Find the `MouseDown` entry and change the dropdown to the right of
   it to `pictureBox1_MouseDown`.
4. Find the `MouseMove` entry and change the dropdown to the right of
   it to `pictureBox1_MouseMove`.

Now run it and drag the pictureBox1 around.

EDIT: Here is how to make the code work for multiple controls, as outlined in my comment below.

```
    bool isDragged = false;
    Point ptOffset;

    private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            isDragged = true;
            Button btn = (Button)sender;
            ptOffset = new Point(btn.Location.X - Cursor.Position.X, btn.Location.Y - Cursor.Position.Y);
        }
        else
        {
            isDragged = false;
        }
    }

    private void button1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isDragged)
        {
            Point newPoint = Cursor.Position;
            newPoint.Offset(ptOffset);
            Button btn = (Button)sender;
            btn.Location = newPoint;
        }
    }

    private void button1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        isDragged = false;
    }
```

Comment: Damn, i'm stupid. I'm sorry for your iconvenience :) Thanks a lot! You get the accepted answer here ;) You solved a big problem for me!

Comment: You're not stupid...you're learning; and it's not an inconvenience.  Some event handlers do actually work without needing to be wired up.  Those methods will have `override` at the beginning of them, and the names normally start with "On" such as "OnClick".  You'll figure out the difference...keep programming!

Comment: On a side note, some languages do actually automatically associate a method with a specific event based solely on naming convention.  Microsoft's own legacy VB6 worked this way, as does code in VBA for MS Office applications.

Comment: By the way @Idle_Mind can you help me in a chat with something about the MouseDown()? I don't want to post a new thread, just to get that explained :) I want to create this mouse-drag to most of those objects i have in the form. I tried some stupid code where i tried to create a variable when the mouse where held down on the object. "Private String selectedObject = e.Location.GetObjectName;" or something like that. (The object would be for example a picture.) What should i do here?

Comment: I'm kinda getting the hang of it right now, i guess. I got a lot of things done already

Comment: Those same handlers can be used for any number of buttons simply by using the `sender` parameter, which will be a reference to the source of the event.  You just need to cast `sender` to the correct type before using it.  You can wire the controls up to the same handler using the process I outlined above thru the IDE, or by using code to wire them up at run-time (this would be useful for dynamic controls created at run-time).  I'll edit my post to show what I mean.

Comment: Wow, thank you! :) I was thinking about something like "String selectedItem = GetChildAtPoint;" and then "ptOffset.X = selectedItem.Location.X - ptStartPosition.X;" Does not work as you might have guessed.

Comment: Hmm.. It doesn't seem to recognize MouseDownLocation. Are you sure that's correct? :)

Comment: I'm sure.  `MouseDownLocation` was already declared and in the code; see **YOUR** original post.  I only changed the pictureBox1_MouseMove() method.  The rest of the code you originally had would still need to be there.

Comment: Wait a minute.. I found another code, that was better because that code i posted would move the whole form. I'm really sorry! Let me get the other code put on this thread instead.

Comment: It's the same concept.  Instead of hard-coding a control, cast sender to the correct type.  I've edited my post.

Comment: Thanks again! I got it in my code now. I added a new "PictureBox pcb = (PictureBox)sender;" Although it doesn't work :( (Crashes) Here's a little pastebin http://pastebin.com/2M07eHQW It's okay if you don't wanna help! :) You've done enough. A big thanks from me!

Comment: Just cast everything to Control, `Control ctl = (Control)sender;`, and use "ctl" in that code.  If a Button fired that event, then you can't cast a Button to a PictureBox and vice versa.  Both of them, however, can be cast to Control because they derive from that class.

Comment: THANKS THANKS THANKS! IT FINALLY WORKS!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the good news: hopefully we'll have a CSI desktop layout once you're done.

The not so good news: I think you're trying to do the wrong thing.

I'm assuming you're using WinForms, but the idea should be the same for WPF. 
When you run your program, the layout is set (either dynamically, for example it changes when you resize the window, or statically, for example when you set it with absolute X,Y position).

What you want to do is kind of: I want to get the benefits of them creating all the boiler plate code, but then, I want to dynamically change it at run time ...

I think you need to rethink your approach, and take this one step at a time (after all, it took Microsoft years to get the GUI to where it's at at the moment ... It'll take some time to get the cool futuristic GUI's out).

Take baby steps, but keep in mind the big picture:

- Start with having a Canvas defined.
- Then you can place a button on it.
- Then fool around with moving that button on the canvas. (The code you have in your question should work for an object on a canvas).

From there, keep taking steps that will get you closer to your destination ...

Comment: Thank you so much!

A little status update:
-Still haven't made any drag/drop mouse thing
-I've created like a desktop using the FlowLayoutPanel
-Added a NewFormIcon like on a desktop, and when you click it, it opens a form2 within form1 (MdiContainer)
-Fullscreen mode
-Exit application (Ofcourse)

But don't expect me to ever be done with this! ;) I suck at it pretty much.

Comment: All starts are hard ... if you enjoy it , keep doing it ... it'll become easier ... :)